# gobject.timeout_add example

Tags: ruby, gtk

I need to perform some actions periodically on my GTK Ruby program and i am looking for the working example of using gobject.timeout_add() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a short example showing a timeout each second that prints the message `foo`. The true at the end of the timeout block means that you don't want to remove the timeout. Return false when you want the timeout to stop firing.

```
require 'glib2'

GLib::Timeout.add(1000) do 
  puts "foo"            
  true
end

mainloop = GLib::MainLoop.new
mainloop.run
```

Comment: Thanks. The true at the end of block is that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution, but I am not sure:

```
class MainWin 
   def initialize() 
     @window = Gtk::Window::new 
     .... 
     periodic 
   end 

   def periodic 
     do_something 
     Glib::Timeout.add(100) { periodic } 
   end
 end
```